# How to convert from Moment to Luxon for two letter day of week format?

Tags: format, momentjs, dayofweek, luxon

I am converting a typescript app to use Luxon instead of Moment for datetime processing and am not sure how to use Luxon's built-in features (or configurable options) to return the day of week as two letters.

Moment:
`moment().format('MM/dd/y')` should return `'04/Tu/2022'`.

Luxon:
`DateTime.now().toFormat('MM/ccc/yyyy')` but that gives me `'04/Tue/2022'`, which does not fit the required backend data format.

Is there an options parameter I can set to specify the number of letters to return for the day of week string?  Or another approach?

This is an example that I found that allows you to specify 2 digit day and month using options...

`DateTime.now().toLocaleString({ day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })` => `05/10/2022`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that this is not possible "*natively*" with Luxon, [Table of tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens) lists only `ccc` (day of the week, as an abbreviate localized string), `cccc` (day of the week, as an unabbreviated localized string), `ccccc` (day of the week, as a single localized letter) that maps exactly the possible values (`'narrow'`, `'short'`, `'long'`) of weekday key of the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) option [object](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-datetimeformat-abstracts).

Possible workaround is to use custom function and get only first two digit of day of the week.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

function customFormat(dt) {
  const year = dt.year;
  const month = dt.toFormat('MM');
  const dow = dt.toFormat('ccc').substring(0, 2);
  return month + '/' + dow + '/' + year;
}

console.log(customFormat(DateTime.now()));
console.log(customFormat(DateTime.fromISO('2022-05-11')));
console.log(customFormat(DateTime.fromISO('2022-05-10')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is a shame they don't include 'cc' for a more direct conversion from moment.  As you mention it doesn't seem to fit into their concept of only using 'narrow', 'short', 'long' for all things related.  

In the end, I used a similar approach to remove the third character.

`this.removeByIndex(DateTime.now().toFormat('MM/ccc/y hh:mm:ss a'), 5)`
`...`
`removeByIndex(str: string, index: number) {`
`  return str.slice(0, index) + str.slice(index + 1);`
`}`